# Find group by count for multiple columns and append it to original DataFrame , giving keyError with the field name, in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tried to find a group by count for multiple columns and append it to original DataFrame. Tried the below and got some error. What could be going wrong.

colList: are the List of columns I would like to retain in the DataFrame, which are not part of group by fields.

```
def addCounts(x,colList):
    #print(x.columns)
    res = x[colList]
    res['Prb_B_conf_sum'] = x.apply(lambda el : x['Prb_B_conf']+ el['Prb_B_conf'], axis=1)
    res['Prb_R_conf_sum'] = x.apply(lambda el : x['Prb_R_conf']+ el['Prb_R_conf'], axis=1)
    # May more Colums Simlar lines ..
    res

trainPrepared = train_stack.groupby(['Main_ID', 'Sub_ID']).apply(addCounts,colListTrain)
```

Received Error:

> pandas_libs\index.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._maybe_get_bool_indexer()
>   **KeyError**: 'Prb_B_conf_sum' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred ... **ValueError**: Wrong number of items
>   passed 7, placement implies 1

## Sample input

```
  Main_ID Sub_ID ID ID_2 Prb_B_conf Prb_R_conf
0       M      A  1  1.1          0          0
1       M      B  2  2.1          0          0
2       M      A  3  3.3          1          2
3       M      B  4  4.3          1          2
4       M      A  5  5.3          2          2
5       M      B  6  6.3          2          2
6       M      A  7  7.3          1          1
7       M      B  8  8.3          1          1
```

## Expected output fields are

```
Main_ID,Sub_ID,ID,ID_2,Prb_B_conf,Prb_B_conf_sum,Prb_R_conf_sum

M,A,1,1.1,0,0, Sum(Prb_B_conf, when Main_ID=M,Sub_ID=A),Sum(Prb_R_conf, when Main_ID=M,Sub_ID=A)
```

Comment: Can you please add sample dataset and your expected outcome? It help reproduce the error

Comment: @SIA, I have added some sample

Comment: Can you show the expected output in tabular format?